# Python objects aren't accepting arguments

Tags: python, function, object, methods

I am trying to create a snake in python, I am doing this through an object that will be a snake. I am trying to call a `createSnake` function from inside my object but the arguments aren't being accepted.

My IDE is returning:

```
TypeError: createsnake() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_coordinate'
```

Here is my snake code:

```
class Snake(object):
def createsnake(self, x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
    grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 2
```

And here is how I am calling the method:

```
Snake.createsnake(1, 1)
```

Comment: What is the point of `createsnake()` rather than `__init__()`?

Answer (score 3):

When a function has a `self` parameter, that means it must be called from an instance of the class.

This means you can't call `createsnake` directly from the class `Snake`; you have to *make* a `Snake` first.

```
snake = Snake()
snake.createsnake(1, 1)
```

Alternatively, if you *do* want to be able to call the function from the `Snake` class, you should make the function static:

```
class Snake(object):
    @staticmethod
    def createsnake(x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
        grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 2

Snake.createsnake(1, 1)
```

Another option, since your function is meant to perform some sort of initialization, is to change the function to be a constructor, so that it is executed as soon as you create a new `Snake`:

```
class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self, x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
        grid[x_coordinate][y_coordinate] = 2

snake = Snake(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not calling the create method on an instance of Snake. It is complaining because you don't pass in a parameter to the "self" parameter because you are calling it on the Snake class. An instance of snake will supply the self parameter.

try

`snake = Snake()
snake.createsnake(1,1)`